# jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 css wont work for multilingual website

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I am working on a multilingual  mobile version of an asp.net webform based website. So far thing are going fine except one problem that is when i switch from one language to another language application download corrects version of CSS but fails to take effect unless i dont press Ctrl + F5.

I am using English & Arabic version which use LTR & RTL direction so css needs to be changed.

I am not sure if css is being cached somehow even if HTML Source code shows the correct version of css for each language as shown below.

**English version**

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script/jquery.mobile-1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href='script/jquery.mobile-1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='style/mobile-english.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

**Arabic Version**

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script/jquery.mobile-1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href='script/jquery.mobile-1.3.0/jquery.mobile-arabic-1.3.0.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='style/mobile-arabic.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

**Scenario**

For example if i go to English version first & then click Arabic version it will using English CSS not arabic css same happens vice versa. But if i press CTRL + F5 then it then uses the correct version of css

I would appreciate help in this regard

Comment: You mean styles are not applied when you switch languages?

Comment: @Omar:- For example if i do to english version first & then click arabic version it will using english CSS not arabic css same happens vice versa. But if i press CTRL + F5 then it download the uses the correct version of css

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you could refresh the same page after loading the new styles.

```
$.mobile.changePage(
 window.location.href, { // or '#PageID'
    allowSamePageTransition: true,
    transition: 'none',
    showLoadMsg: false,
    reloadPage: true // Forces page reload if you're using 'window.location.href' or url
});
```

The above code will reload the page without `transition` and refresh its contents.

Here's a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/jDfhH/).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work  by using following jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form, a').removeAttr('data-ajax');
    $('form, a').attr('data-ajax', false);
});
```

I tried several solution but none of them worked as it kept using CSS which was download first time that either English or Arabic version.

Disabling cache may have other problems but on the other side i have to use the correct version of css